# New class between old class and its subclasses in Protege

Tags: protege

Supposing I have an OWL class `class_1` with subclasses: `sub_1`, `sub_2`, `sub_3`, how do I turn `sub_1`, `sub_2`, `sub_3` into subclasses of a new class named `new_class`, and make `new_class` to be subclass of `class_1` ? I am googling it, without any success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `new_class` as a subclass of `class_1` by selecting `class_1` and clicking on the add class button. You can then select the other classes you wish to modify and add `new_class` as a superclass (the options are available in the detail pane). There's no need to remove the previous subclass relationships as they are still true in the new setup.